# Django translations not working with Django-cms and djangocms-blog

Tags: django, internationalization, django-cms

I have a problem with my Django Translations.
My Django doesn't translate my tags.

I use [django-cms](https://github.com/divio/django-cms) and in django-cms I have a plugin [djangocms-blog](https://github.com/nephila/djangocms-blog).

Django == 1.6.5

Django-cms == 3.0.3

Djangocms-blog == 0.2b5

**My transtags are not translated.**

Example tag:

```
{% trans "read more" %}
```

I installed everything correctly, my settings.py contains this:

```
gettext = lambda s: s

# Internationalization
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'nl'
TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Brussels'
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
USE_TZ = True

LOCALE_PATHS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'locale'),
)

LANGUAGES = (
    ('nl', _(u'Dutch')),
    ('fr', _(u'French')),
    ('en', _(u'English')),
)

CMS_LANGUAGES = {
    1: [
        {
            'code': 'nl',
            'name': gettext('Dutch'),
            'fallbacks': ['en', 'fr'],
            'public': True,
            'hide_untranslated': True,
            'redirect_on_fallback':False,
        },
        {
            'code': 'en',
            'name': gettext('English'),
            'fallbacks': ['nl'],
            'public': False,
            'hide_untranslated': True,
            'redirect_on_fallback':False,
        },
        {
            'code': 'fr',
            'name': gettext('French'),
            'public': False,
            'hide_untranslated': True,
        },
    ],
    2: [
        {
            'code': 'nl',
            'name': gettext('Dutch'),
            'public': True,
            'fallbacks': ['en'],
        },
    ],
    'default': {
        'fallbacks': ['en', 'fr'],
        'redirect_on_fallback': True,
        'public': False,
        'hide_untranslated': False,
    }
}
```

In My Middleware classes:

```
    MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.doc.XViewMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.flatpages.middleware.FlatpageFallbackMiddleware',

    'cms.middleware.page.CurrentPageMiddleware',
    'cms.middleware.user.CurrentUserMiddleware',
    'cms.middleware.toolbar.ToolbarMiddleware',
    'cms.middleware.language.LanguageCookieMiddleware',
)
```

My urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.conf.urls.i18n import i18n_patterns
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings

admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = i18n_patterns(
    '',
    url(r'^i18n/', include('django.conf.urls.i18n')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^products/', include('catalog.urls')),
    url(r'^contact/', 'contact.views.contact'),
    url(r'^pages/', include('django.contrib.flatpages.urls')),
    url(r'^taggit_autosuggest/', include('taggit_autosuggest.urls')),
    url(r'^', include('cms.urls')),
)

if settings.DEBUG:
    import debug_toolbar
    urlpatterns = i18n_patterns('',
        url(r'^__debug__/', include(debug_toolbar.urls)),
        url(r'^404/$', 'django.views.defaults.page_not_found'), # TODO MOET NOG VERPLAATST WORDEN
        url(r'^500/$', 'django.views.defaults.server_error'), # TODO MOET NOG VERPLAATST WORDEN
        url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',
            {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'show_indexes': True}),
        url(r'', include('django.contrib.staticfiles.urls')),
    ) + urlpatterns
```

In my blog_items.html page (a page from the djangocms-blog plugin template that I override)

```
{% load i18n thumbnail cms_tags %}
{% load url from future %}
```

I created my languages within the virtual env by

1. Going to the virtual env by "workon app"
2. I run the command django-admin.py makemessages -l nl (the po files are created correctly)
3. I run the command django-admin.py compilemessages and everything seems fine
4. In the root of my program is the locale folder  with 3 subfolders: en, fr and nl. They contain all the LC_MESSAGES folder with a django.mo and django.po file with the correct message strings.

   `#: .\templates\djangocms_blog\includes\blog_item.html:37 #, fuzzy
   msgid "read more"
   msgstr "lees meer"`

Comment: Have you enabled i18n in django-cms?
http://docs.django-cms.org/en/latest/advanced/i18n.html

Comment: Yes, this is my urls:
`
urlpatterns = i18n_patterns(
    url(r'^', include('cms.urls')),
)`

Comment: Is the Middleware (cms.middleware.language.LanguageCookieMiddleware) also in your settings?

Comment: Yes:
'cms.middleware.language.LanguageCookieMiddleware',

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is solved.

1. First of all the fuzzy had to be removed.
2. I had to add the parler settings correct into my general settings:

In the documentation of Django-parler (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-parler ) they suggest the next settings:

```
PARLER_LANGUAGES = {
    None: (
        {'code': 'nl',},
        {'code': 'en',},
        {'code': 'fr',},
    ),
}
```

Instead of

```
PARLER_LANGUAGES = {
    1: (
        {'code': 'nl',},
        {'code': 'en',},
        {'code': 'fr',},
    ),
}
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK translations marked as `fuzzy` are not compiled in the mo files and you must "unfuzzy" them before being available